# Combinatorial product of regex substitutions

Tags: python, regex, cross-product

I am trying to produce string variants by applying substitutions optionally.

For example, one substitution scheme is removing any sequence of blank characters.
Rather than replacing all occurrences like

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', 'a b c')
'abc'
```

– I need, instead, two variants to be produced for each occurrence, in that the substitution is performed in one variant, but not in the other.
For the string `'a b c'`
I want to have the variants

```
['a b c', 'a bc', 'ab c', 'abc']
```

ie. the cross product of all binary decisions (the result obviously includes the original string).

For this case, the variants can be produced using `re.finditer` and `itertools.product`:

```
def vary(target, pattern, subst):
    occurrences = [m.span() for m in pattern.finditer(target)]
    for path in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=len(occurrences)):
        variant = ''
        anchor = 0
        for (start, end), apply_this in zip(occurrences, path):
            if apply_this:
                variant += target[anchor:start] + subst
                anchor = end
        variant += target[anchor:]
        yield variant
```

This produces the desired output for the above example:

```
>>> list(vary('a b c', re.compile(r'\s+'), ''))
['abc', 'ab c', 'a bc', 'a b c']
```

However, this solution only works for fixed-string replacements.
Advanced features from `re.sub` like group references can't be done like that,
as in the following example for inserting a space after a sequence of digits inside a word:

```
re.sub(r'\B(\d+)\B'), r'\1 ', 'abc123def')
```

How can the approach be extended or changed to accept any valid argument to re.sub
(without writing a parser for interpreting group references)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about making `subst` a callable that gets access to match data finally made me learn about `MatchObject.expand`. So, as an approximation, with `subst` staying an `r` string,

```
def vary(target, pattern, subst):
    matches = [m for m in pattern.finditer(target)]
    occurrences = [m.span() for m in matches]
    for path in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=len(occurrences)):
        variant = ''
        anchor = 0
        for match, (start, end), apply_this in zip(matches, occurrences, path):
            if apply_this:
                variant += target[anchor:start] + match.expand(subst)
                anchor = end
        variant += target[anchor:]
        yield variant
```

I am not sure, though, that this covers all needed flexibility in referring to the subject string, being bount to the corresponding match. An indexed power set of the split string came to mind, but I guess that's not far from the parser mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good hint! The limitations for a callable argument can be dropped easily by making it the general case: in the inner loop, replace `... + match.expand(subst)` with `... + subst(match)`. If the argument isn't a callable to begin with, just wrap in a function (at the beginning of the code): `if not callable(subst): static_subst = subst; subst = lambda m: m.expand(static_subst)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def vary(target, pattern, subst):
  numOccurences = len (pattern.findall (target))

  for path in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=numOccurences):

    variant       = ''
    remainingStr = target

    for currentFlag in path:

      if currentFlag: 
        remainingStr = pattern.sub (subst, remainingStr, 1)
      else:
        currentMatch = pattern.search (remainingStr);
        variant += remainingStr[:currentMatch.end ()]
        remainingStr = remainingStr[currentMatch.end ():]

    variant += remainingStr

    yield variant
```

For each match, we either let re.sub() do its job (with a count of 1 to stop after one substitution), or we snatch away the unchanged portion of the string.

Trying it out with your examples like this

```
target = 'a b c'
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
subst = ''

print list (vary(target, pattern, subst))

target = 'abc123def'
pattern = re.compile(r'\B(\d+)\B')
subst = r'\1 '

print list (vary(target, pattern, subst))
```

I get

```
['abc', 'ab c', 'a bc', 'a b c']
['abc123 def', 'abc123def']
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem with clipping the target string before applying `re.sub` is that it removes necessary context in some corner cases. For example, the pattern `r'\B(\d+|[A-Z]+)\B'` will match 'A' in the string `'abc1Adef'`, but not in the clipped version `'Adef'`. I know I'm picking rare cases here, but this is exactly the kind of situations that produces hard-to-trace bugs.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- this approach was too naïve to cover all nasty corner-cases...